# MVC 5 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable to bool?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

For the life of me I cannot figure how I am getting the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'bool?'` if I double-click the error it takes me to the HomeController and highlights the select statement within the line `statsModel.Donations = (from q in db.Shows where (q.Id == 1) select new { q.Donations });`.

**Show.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Show
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Donations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**StatsisticsModel.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    using System;

    public class StatisticsModels
    {
        public int UserCount { get; set; }
        public decimal? TotalAmount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Donations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Statistics()
{
    var statsModel = new StatisticsModels();
    statsModel.UserCount = (from m in db.AspNetUsers where (m.UserName != "someone") && (m.EmailConfirmed == true) select new { m.UserName }).Count();
    statsModel.TotalAmount = db.Donations.Sum(o => o.Amount);
    statsModel.Donations = (from q in db.Shows where (q.Id == 1) select new { q.Donations });
    return View(statsModel);
}
```

Can anyone please help, all I want to return is whether the Donations and People fields within the Show table are true or false for a particular record.

Any help would me much appreciated :-)

Comment: Seems pretty clear - `Donations` is defined as a `Nullable<bool>` but you're assigning a query to it.  Should the query be returning a single true/false value instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `Donations` is a boolean field in your model and you only expect one record for tat ID I think you just want:

```
statsModel.Donations = (from q in db.Shows where (q.Id == 1) select q.Donations).Single();
```

or

```
statsModel.Donations = db.Shows.Where(q => q.Id == 1).Single(q => q.Donations);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with this line:

```
 statsModel.Donations = (from q in db.Shows where (q.Id == 1) select new { q.Donations });
```

This will try to assign the a collection of anonymous type object to `Donations` which is can hold a single value (Nullable).

> all I want to return is whether the Donations and People fields within
>   the Show table are true or false for a particular record.

You need something like:

```
statsModel.Donations = db.Shows.Any(q=> q.Id == 1);
```

If your field `Donations` in database is of type boolean, then you need to get a single instance of that from your query, using either `First/FirstOrDefault`, `Single/SingleOrDefault` depending on your requirement.

```
statsModel.Donations = (from q in db.Shows where (q.Id == 1) select q.Donations)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```