# Search an element on list inside the list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, linq

I am using Linq query to for searching, I have a list `productList` on which I am searching some data and a part from this I have an another list `IQProductSkuList` into above list.

So I have to search the data into the entire retrieved data but whenever I am going to find the into the list that resides in another list it gives an error as below.

> Can not implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Iqueryable' to bool
>
> Can not convert lambda expression to intend delegate because some of
>   the return type in the block are not implicitly convertible to the
>   delegate return type

Here is my code

First search on main list

```
 productList = productList.Where
       (x => 
            (x.ProductName ?? "").ToLower().Contains(searchingkey.ToLower().Trim())
         || (x.ProductAbbreviation ?? "").ToLower().Contains(searchingkey.ToLower().Trim())
         || (x.ProductDisplayName ?? "").ToLower().Contains(searchingkey.ToLower().Trim())
         || (x.DestinationName ?? "").ToLower().Contains(searchingkey.ToLower().Trim())
         || (x.DestinationCityName ?? "").ToLower().Contains(searchingkey.ToLower().Trim())
        );
```

It works fine but when i am searching on list inside `productList` it gives an error.

Here is code for search on list inside the list that throws the exception.

```
productList = productList.ToList().Where(x => x.IQProductSkuList.Where
             (
                 x => (x.SKUCode ?? "").ToLower().Contains(searchingkey.ToLower().Trim()))
             );
```

Please help me any kind of help will be appreciated..

Comment: Where returns a List of Objects and not a Boolean. Try x.IQProductSkuList.Any(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC 5 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable to bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787942/mvc-5-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-linq-iqueryable-to-bool)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) is what you are looking for. It returns:

> `true` if the source sequence contains any elements; otherwise, `false`.

```
productList = productList.ToList().Where(x => x.IQProductSkuList.Any
                  (
                    x => (x.SKUCode ?? "").ToLower().Contains(searchingkey.ToLower().Trim())
                  ));
```

Actually the [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) method is demanding it.
If you look in the documentation then you'll see that it expects this type of parameter:

> predicate
>   `Func<TSource,Boolean>`
>   A function to test each element for a condition.

That means that the input of the function is of type `TSource` and the return value has to be of type `Boolean`.

The return type of `Any` matches that:

> Returns
>   `Boolean`

your problem was the mismatch because of the return value of the `Where` method:

> Returns
>   `IEnumerable<TSource>`

Comment: thanks sysntax error has been solved.let me check on data and thank you so much for your effort and valueable time